# Does adding the input signals change the behaviour of an amplifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier, signal

[image]

I have these 3 signals, they differ by 300 Hz each. When I use any of these signals as input to a class B amplifier, I get the desired current amplification. The thing is, I have to input all these 3 signals at the same time to the speaker(my load). My plan to do it to use an adding op-Amp configuration. However, I wonder will the amplifier work properly or will there be any problems?

Also, what are the chances that I suffer from momentary excess voltages on
the load, an 8 ohms speaker in fact, which may result in damage to the speaker?
Thanks in advance.

edit : I don't know does it affect the question but I think I have to add that, actually at any time instant only two of the three signals will be active, and one of them will be lower in amplitude relative the other one.

Comment: ... unless the there isn't enough headroom in your +/- voltage rails and the the summed signal clips, I don't see why that would be a problem. Because Fourier and all that jazz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The 3 signals will not change the behavior of the operational amplifier, providing the op amp continues to operate in its linear region.  It if starts to compress, saturate, or limit, then it starts to act like a mixer and you may start to see  new frequencies in the output.